# COMC Problem of the Week Problem

Tags: contest-math

[Problem of the Week- Week 5 of COMC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azZrP.png)

Can anyone please tell me if my solution is correct.

So, I divide the equation by "$a_n$" in the numerator and denominator ($a_n$ cannot be zero).

I get:  $a_{n+1} =$ 1 / (n + 1/(a_n))

Using this new equation, I find $a_{n + 1}$ in terms of $a_{n - 1}$, then $a_{n -2}$ and so on. I see the pattern is

$a_{n + 1} =$ 1 / (sum of numbers k to n + (1 / a_k))

I substitute $n + 1 = 1996$, $n = 1995$, $k = 2$, and solve for $a_2$.

Then I get $a_{1996}$ is $\frac{1}{1991011}$

Answer (score 0):

If
$a_{n+1} 
=\dfrac1{n+\frac1{a_n}}
$
then
$\dfrac1{a_{n+1}} 
=n+\dfrac1{a_n}
$.

Letting
$b_n
=\dfrac1{a_n}
$,
$b_{n+1}
=n+b_n
$,
or
$b_{n+1}-b_n = n$.

Summing from
$1$ to $m-1$,
$b_m-b_1
=\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}(b_{n+1}-b_n)
=\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}n
=m(m-1)/2
$,
so
$b_m
=1+m(m-1)/2
=(m^2-m+2)/2
$
so that
$a_m
=\dfrac{2}{m^2-m+2}
$.

If
$m = 1996$,
$(m^2-m+2)/2
=1991011
$,
so I agree.